# jQuery Ajax 404 Handling 

Tags: jquery

Im trying to access a 404 event which I can see coming back as 404 with firebug but the error function is not kicking in, With my below code I always get Error: success ?.

ie.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'url: 'https://admin.instantservice.com/resources/smartbutton/5702/10945/available.gif?' + Math.floor(Math.random()*10001),
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        console.log('Error: ' + textStatus);
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(xhr.statusText);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Again I know 1000% that im getting 404 Not Found in firebug it never triggers the error.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: I tested that exact same code and got the 3 error alerts correctly (first was `404`)..

Comment: Are you sure that you actually get a response with the status code 404, and not just a regular response with status code 200 and a page that contains text that says that it's a 404?

Comment: @cambraca Same over here. Tested with Firefox 3.6.12 and Firebug.

Comment: next time use `console.log()` for debugging. It saves the javascript locking up and is less obtrusive. It comes up in your javascript console.

Comment: Now I have enter the URL I am actually trying. Please try now

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Cross Site requests, JSONP, wont trigger the error calls. Just had the same problem myself: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-with-datatype-jsonp-will-not-use-error-callback-if-request-fails

Comment: And what about non-jsonp request, which was not identified in the question?

Comment: Note that when you specify a timeout (in milliseconds), the error will be called.

Comment: Altough $.getJSON catches 404's fine with .error() method

Answer (score 14):

What you can also do is use the     $.ajaxError function, like so

```
$("#message").ajaxError(function (event, request, settings) {
    $(this).show();
    $(this).append("<li>Error requesting page " + settings.url + "</li>");
});
```

Comment: Not sure why this doesn't have more upvotes, works perfect see: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Comment: Thanks @systematical - not sure myself, works great for me, I have it in the boilerplate for all my sites.

Comment: The reason this was not helpful for me was because it still does not get called in the case of JSONP. From http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/: "Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests."

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar result/problem. The bottom line is that I failed to **make sure that my URL did not contain any of the same param names in the data section** of the ajax function.

---

The reason for me, was that I generated the URL with php code to get a url

```
pines_url('com_referral', 'sendhttprequest')
```

which outputs to a url with a parameter

```
option=com_referral
```

and a parameter

```
action=sendhttprequest
```

My BIG problem was that I was also trying to send a param "action" in the data section of an AJAX function.

```
data: {"action": "getpoints"}
```

So the second action was overriding it "getpoints" does not exist, but the tricky part is that firebug would obviously not tell me the url with getpoints, it would tell me the url as sendhttprequest.

Hope that wasn't confusing, but I also hope this helps someone else with a similar problem!

Answer (score 1):

Adding a timeout value will cause the error callback to run if there is no response in the specified time.  With a callback of 5000, if the jsonp request doesn't respond in 5 seconds (i.e. it 404s) then the error callback will run.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    timeout: 5000,
    url: 'url: 'https://admin.instantservice.com/resources/smartbutton/5702/10945/available.gif?' + Math.floor(Math.random()*10001),
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        console.log('Error: ' + textStatus);
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(xhr.statusText);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: This assumes a 404 takes at least 5 seconds to be served?

Comment: Yes, 5 seconds is a fairly aggressive default. If you're connecting to a slow server you could go up to 30 seconds but at the detriment of user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why, but if you use the chaining `.fail` method, the error is correctly captured even if it is a different site:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'http://example.com',
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        console.log('Error: ' + textStatus);
      }
    }).fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(xhr.statusText);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    });
```

Comment: I just tried this out, fail method will NOT be executed if the call is cross site request and gets 404.

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'url: ' in your code

Your code :

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'url: 'https://admin.instantservice.com/resources/smartbutton/5702/10945/available.gif?' + Math.floor(Math.random()*10001),
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        console.log('Error: ' + textStatus);
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(xhr.statusText);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Correct code :

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'https://admin.instantservice.com/resources/smartbutton/5702/10945/available.gif?' + Math.floor(Math.random()*10001),
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        console.log('Error: ' + textStatus);
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(xhr.statusText);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```