# Check for 404 error status in jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, twitter

I use this code to get some information from twitter via their api:

```
        $.ajax({
            url : apiUrl,
            cache : false,
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success : function(html) {
                // ...
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        });
```

However, if the **apiUrl** variable provides a correct url, this code work fine, e.i. the success object is executed, but if the url isn't correct, e.i. 404 error is returned from twitter, the error object is never executed. It doesn't log anything in console. How should I check for 404 error status in this case?

Comment: This might solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281274/jquery-ajax-404-handling

Comment: give an example of an incorrect url

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4803044/137972 might be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From jQuery API ajax docs:

`error option`

> Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP
>   requests.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, use `statusCode` setting in `.ajax`.

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  statusCode: {
    404: function(){
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: nop, this isn't executed as well. I'm afraid the first reply to this topic is correct... http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-with-datatype-jsonp-will-not-use-error-callback-if-request-fails