# No error handling in jQuery AJAX call invoked

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, error-handling

I'm trying to make the AJAX call bark and squick at me so I'm executing a totally wrong URL. For some reason, none of the methods that are supposed to do the barking och squicking is invoked.

What is the reason?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://totally.wrong.url",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  error: function () { alert("bark 1"); },
  failure: function () { alert("bark 2"); }
})
  .fail(function () { alert("squick"); })
  .done(function () { alert("woof"); });
```

Of course, if I change the URL to point to the correct WCF service, I get an approving woof.

According to [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), I should use *fail* and *done* syntax but I'll be fine either way.

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: try `error` instead of `failure`

Comment: @KhanhTO Tried that too. To no avail. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281274/jquery-ajax-404-handling. They propose using `ajaxError`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax with JSONP and Cross Site Requests won't trigger the error callback.

Look at the accepted answer in this question: [jQuery Ajax 404 Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281274/jquery-ajax-404-handling)

Hopefully this should explain what you need to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if failure is supposed to work but I always use "error" and "success" instead.
So try:

```
   $.ajax({
      url: "http://totally.wrong.url",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      error: function () { alert("bark");},
      success: function () { alert("woof");} 
      }
    })
```

Comment: Didn't work either. I forgot to say that. I started with *error* and then tried *failure*.  :)

Comment: Yes sorry I saw you mentioned that after I posted it.

Comment: Also, according to the information at one of the links I've received, there's no error message delivered when using JSONP. Are you able to make the code in your reply work and do you see it actually barking?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://totally.wrong.url",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  **error**: function () { alert("bark"); }
})
  .fail(function () { alert("squick"); })
  .done(function () { alert("woof"); });
```

`error` is the request fail callback function and not `failure`

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question. Tried *error* first of all, hehe. Didn't work.