# jQuery AJAX error callback not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have an AJAX call as follows:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx.js",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("success");
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log("done");
    }).fail(function(data){
        console.log("fail");
    }).always(function(){
        console.log("always")
    });
```

When the call succeeds, the `success` and `done` functions run. However, when the call fails (like when I change the url to gobbledygook) nothing runs, not even `always`.

The behavior happens in both Firefox and Chrome.

I've seen a number of other people mention that it's a problem with `JSONP`, and the accepted answer says that making it `async: false` would work, but neither `async: false` nor `async: true` worked.

What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281274/jquery-ajax-404-handling

Comment: Thanks, a comment there helped out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround that worked is adding a `timeout`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx.js",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    timeout: 5000
}).done(function(data){
    console.log("done");
}).fail(function(data){
    console.log("fail");
}).always(function(){
    console.log("always")
});
```

Then after 5 seconds, the error/always works.