# Allow code execution to continue after recieving 404 error while using REST

Tags: javascript, rest

I am working on a tool that allows the user to type some IDs, and check if these IDs exist in the database.

The code was written to work with SOLR database, so if the ID didn't exist there was no problem. Now though I am talking to CouchDB, so if the ID doesn't exist, the tool will give no result and produce a 404 error: 404 (Object Not Found).

Here is my code:

```
// ...

    function caller() {
        if (validIDs.length === 0) {
            promise.resolve();

            return;
        }

        var ID = validIDs.pop();
        var url = preURL + ID;
        var wrappedResult = {
            "ID": ID,
            "data": undefined
        };

        $.getJSON(url).done(function(data) {
            wrappedResult["data"] = data;
            caller();
        });

        wrappedResults.push(wrappedResult);
    }

    caller();

    return [promise, wrappedResults];
}
```

I tried to use something like:

```
$.getJSON({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        wrappedResult["data"] = data;
        myForEach();
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('error');
    },
    complete: function(xhr, data) {
        if (xhr.status !== 0)
            alert('success');
        else
            alert('fail');
    }
});
```

But it did not work. the html doesn't display the table, and in the console: 404 (Object Not Found)

I looked at the solution suggested in other similar question but they did not solve my problem.

Please is there a way my code can continue showing the results of the accepted IDs and point out the invalid ones?

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work"?  Did you get an error? Is anything in the console?

Comment: yes the console shows the url and writes: 404 (Object Not Found).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax 404 Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281274/jquery-ajax-404-handling)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Ajax 404 Handling did not answer my question. 
what solved the problem was using 
    var jqXHR= $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    });
and instead of 
    jqXHR.done(function(data){
    .....});
I used
    jqXHR.always(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
    ........});
the console still shows 404 (Object Not Found), but the code is not stopped and is working

Comment: What version of jquery are you using, this does not work for me?